# Stack of Boxes assignment

Tags: java

We have unlimited number of boxes stacked above eachother.
p=size of the first stack

Each stack is "k" bigger than the stack before that.

```
For example: p=3 k=2
1,2,3
4,5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12,13,14,15
```

Now the assignment is to move one box that a user defines and count how many boxes it has to move above it in order to move that particular box. The user will keep on inserting numbers of boxes for as many days are defined in the variable d.

So the input would go like this:

```
p=3 k=2 d=3(3 days aka 3 boxes to move)
5 (Box 5)
3
12
```

and the output would be: 6 ....why? because it has to move 3 boxes to get the box 5, 0 boxes for the box 3 and 3 boxes for the box 12.

Hopefully, you understood the concept but I had been struggling to correctly put all of this into code.  I had succeeded in some aspects of the assignments but it doesn't seem to be working properly.

It correctly gives me the series of the boxes ...but it doesn't calculate correctly when I input the number....where that number is ( in which stack) and which is the top number for that stack so the program would substrack that and get the num of boxes it had to move.

Hopefully you could help me on what Iam doing wrong and what I should do.

***Here is my code that I tried but doesnt seem to be working:***

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class  A1 {   
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int p = sc.nextInt(); 
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        int d = sc.nextInt();

        int base = 1;
        int size = p;
        int topNum = p+(p+k); 


        int e=0;
        int numBox = 0;
        int movedBox=0;
        int counter = 0;

    while(e<d) {
        numBox = sc.nextInt();
            e++;
        base=base+size; 

        size=size+k;   

        topNum=topNum+(size+k);

        movedBox=topNum-numBox;

counter=movedBox+counter;       

        }
    System.out.println(counter);



        }
    }
```

***UPDATED VERSION:***

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class  SO {   
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int p = sc.nextInt(); 
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        int d = sc.nextInt();


        int height = p;
        int topNum = p; 

        int e=0;
        int numBox = 0;
        int movedBox=0;
        int counter = 0;


    while(e<d) {
        numBox = sc.nextInt();
            e++;
            while(topNum<numBox) { 
                height=height+k;
                topNum = topNum + height;
            }

        movedBox=topNum-numBox;

counter=movedBox+counter;       

        }
    System.out.println(counter);



        }
    }
```

Comment: Please expand on "it does not seem to be working...". What's wrong with your code, how is it not working or misbehaving? Is it compiling? Is it throwing an exception after it starts running? Does it abscond with your wife and daughter? What?

Comment: It correctly gives me the series of the boxes ...but it doesnt calculate correctly when I inut the number....where that number is ( in which stack) and which is the top number for that stack so the program would substrack that and get the num of boxes it had to move.

Comment: Your third stack only has 6 boxes. It should have 7. You should have to move 6 boxes in the example, not 5.

Comment: You are correct, sorry..fixed the mistake :)

Comment: What are the criteria for being able to move a box? I would think you would have to move boxes 1, 2, 3, and 4 to move box 5. Do you just need to be able to reach down from above?

Comment: You need to move all the boxes above the chosen box....talking just about the stack that that particular box is in..

Comment: Can you explain what each of the variables is supposed to represent? I can't follow your calculations.

Comment: p=size os the first stack, k=how much bigger is the next stack of boxes d=days(one day for each box) numBox= number of the box we want to move , base = the base number..lowest number in a stack, topNum=highest number in the stack, size=how many boxes are in a stack, movedBox= how many boxes have we moved for numOfBox ...counter=how many boxes have we moved all together for all the days

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the biggest mistake you make is to add to your variables inside the loop without resetting them first.

Why is that? In the first iteration of the loop, you may get the correct numbers based on the initializations you made outside the box. But then, in the second loop, the numbers are already adjusted for the first moved box (supposedly). But now we move a box from a stack that comes before it, and you add to the numbers that were there from the first moving. So if you had `topNum` as 8 from the first calculation (for box 5), you now add to it! It certainly can't be the correct `topNum` for box 3 if it is a number bigger than 8.

The only variable that should increase from iteration to iteration is the `counter`. All the others need to be reset every time.

But given a box number, you probably want to calculate the stack by looping: starting with p, and then adding p+k numbers and checking if it's the correct stack, and if not, adding another p+2k numbers etc. You need a loop.

I think you got the too loops confused. There should be one outer loop to get the numbers, and one inner loop to calculate the stacks, starting from the first stack every time.

So the math is:

We notice that stack number `n` is always size p + (n-1)×k. The first is 3, the second is 5, the third is 7 boxes tall.

We also notice that each stack ends with a number is the sum of the height of itself plus the previous ones.

- topNumber = p + ( p + k )  + ( p + 2k ) ... ( p + (n-1)×k )

For `n=1` this would be `p` (3). For `n=2` this would be `2p+2` (8), for `n=3` this would be `3p+k+2k` which is `9+2+4` (15).

So for a single box number, given as `numBox`, you do something like:

```
    int topNumber = p;
    int height = p;
    while ( topNumber < numBox ) {
        height += k;
        topNumber += height; 
    }
    movedBoxes = topNumber - numBox;
```

(In case you haven't learned this yet, `x += y` is the same as `x = x + y`).

So you see, you were almost there.

- You shouldn't have added anything to your `base` as you were not using it. In fact if you have a variable you are only assigning to and never actually using, it's not really needed at all.
- You were adding `k` to your `size` (my `height`), which is good. But you were adding another `k` in the next line, which meant it was actually getting the previous size + 2k. You forgot that you already added `k` to that variable so it was already up to date.
- You thought one loop could deal both with retrieving a new number and calculating its `movedBoxes`. It can't be done in one loop. You need to perform the task separately for  each number, and the task itself is in a loop, so you need a loop inside a loop. Be careful to always start the numbers again from `p`.

---

The above method is the naive way of solving this. As you notice, for very high numbers, it is very slow, because it actually goes searching for the first `n` for which the number is in the stack.

In fact, there is a way to solve it without a loop (except the loop that reads the numbers by days, of course). But this requires some math. As we noted, the top number of the nth stack, tₙ, is actually:

> > [image]

That is to say:

> > [image],

Applying Gauss's rule for the arithmetic series:

> > [image]

Now, this is an equation. And if we know what the top number of a stack is, we can solve it for n. That is, if you have a top number tₙ, you can find the `n` by solving the quadratic equation:

> > [image]

And you need, of course, only the positive root of this equation, so:

> > [image]

Which simplifies to:

> > [image]

But we don't necessarily have a top number, right? However, for a given number `t`, we know that it is bigger than the top number of the previous stack, and not more than the top number of its own stack:

> > [image]

This means that if we solve the quadratic equation for this t, the result will be a *real* number (not integer!) `s` such that:

> > [image]

That is, if you round it up, you'll get the n of the stack it is on, and then you can calculate the actual tₙ for that from the formula for tₙ above.

Now, back to programming:

- Have you learned how to create methods yet? If so, I recommend putting the formulas for tₙ and for `n` in separate methods to make your code clear.
- When you calculate divisions with integers, you must be very careful. The formula for tₙ is OK, because the fraction will always produce a proper round number. But the formula for `n` will not be correct if you don't make sure the division is `double` division rather than `integer` division. Never mind the square roots. If you define it in a method, pass the parameters as `double`. If not, make sure you divide k by `2.0` rather than `2`,  k² by `4.0` rather than `4`, and the whole big fraction by `(double)k` rather than `k`.
- Remember to round the result **up**. If you just write `(int)` before it it will be rounded **down**.
- Be careful of division by zero. When you input the value for `k`, make sure it's not zero.

Comment: Thank you @RealSkeptic I had corrected the programme on your notes but the programme still gives the wrong output..  I am really not sure what I am doing wrong now... I am a complete beginner at this.. I posted the updated version above

Comment: You have overlooked one of my comments: you have to reset the variables `topNumber` and `height` **inside** the outer loop. That is, for every new `numBox` they have to start fresh from `p`. Initializing them outside the loop means they will keep their values, which are not correct for the next `numBox`.

Comment: thank you!! It works great now!! you are great! but there is another problem... The teacher only allows the program one second to run....the problem arrives when the number of the boxes are so hight that the program (loops) use way more than just one second to check the movement of the boxes...is there another way to quicken the process? so it doesnt check every stack...so the program could run under 1 second when values are huge numbers

Comment: OK, I thought your teacher wanted you to practice loops, but apparently he wants you to practice quadratic equation solution... So I've updated my answer.

Comment: oh wow... seems way too hard for someone learning programming for 4 weeks ... :/ I must say I dont really understand it that well. I understand the fact that I have to use double here since the result will not be integers and that I must change the top number calculation and the stack calculations, but I am not sure on how to do that in the programing language as you showed above. 

We haven't done methods yet unfortunately. I am sorry if I am too much trouble. I am just a beginner at this @RealSkeptic :(

Comment: I think it would  be best to ask the instructor if he really means for you to solve a quadratic equation and use things like square root and rounding upwards (functions of the java `Math` class) in your program.